# Train large number of independent NNs with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a setting where I need to train a large number of independent NNs. They all share the same architecture, but train and test data is different for each one. The problem I'm finding is that RAM use increases and performance degrades very quickly. Question: how to do this in a efficient and scalable way?

I tried a simple method:

```
for i in range(1000):
    # Create NN
    model = keras.Sequential(...)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)

    # Train and test
    Xtrain, ytrain, Xtest, ytest = loadData(i)
    history = model.fit(XTrain, yTrain, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(Xtest, ytest))

    # Save data
    allHistory.append(history)
```

and then tried to reuse a single NN, reset weights and train:

```
# Create NN
model = keras.Sequential(...)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
# Save fresh model
model.save(savePath)

for i in range(1000):
    # Load fresh model
    model = keras.models.load_model(savePath)

    # Train and test
    Xtrain, ytrain, Xtest, ytest = loadData(i)
    history = model.fit(XTrain, yTrain, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(Xtest, ytest))

    # Save data
    allHistory.append(history)
```

performance and RAM use seem similar in both cases, so I guess TensorFlow keeps growing its graph in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `import thread` and train every NN in an own Thread. This should work since multithreading makes operations sequential and helps to improve its scalability.

I think you'll get good results with:

```
for i in range(0,1000,5):
    t1 = Thread(target=NN, args=arguments(i+1))
    ...
    t5 = Thread(target=NN, args=arguments(i+5))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    ...
    t5.start()
    t5.join()
```

Comment: I just added an example since I think you are performing 1000 Threads at the same time. Maybe this will work for you. I tried to make it as a command but think this way is better.

Comment: This would still incur the ever-growing RAM use problem, as every new model gets added to TF's graph

Comment: Than only use a step size of one start with `t1.start()` and `t1.join()` and end the loop. So the machine will wait till the thread has ended and than start a new one. If this works you can go an increase the step size.